# vim for loop "trailing characters" error

Tags: for-loop, vim

Why does this exceedingly simple function:

```
function! ParseAllEvents()
    let i = 1
    while i > 0 
        exec 'ParseEvent('.i.')'
        let i -= 1
    endwhile
endfunction
```

and/or:

```
function! ParseAllEvents()
    let i = 1
    while i > 0 
        ParseEvent(i)
        let i -= 1
    endwhile
endfunction
```

Generate this error?

**E488: Trailing Characters: ParseEvent(1)**

The `ParseEvent(i)` function works fine when called in the command line

Comment: Vim script is based on ex commands (as well as :exec), so if `ParseEvent` is a function, use `:call ParseEvent(...)` instead. Anyway, this should give you an error in the lines of "not an editor command". So, how is `ParseEvent` defined?

Comment: @sidyll your advice worked.  function! ParseEvent(var) was the definition.  I'm not really clear on when variables are expanded and why functions can seem to be called with 'texttext' . FunName() . 'moretext' And yet other times require the full: call Funname() as you correctly advised.  You've got the green check mark if you post anything.  Thanks!

Comment: I added an answer with a little more info on evaluating expressions. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as we've been discussing in the comments, it was a matter of "calling" the
function by prepending a `:call`.

Generally a  function will  be evaluated anywhere  an expression  is expected,
however this  does not mean that  they are evaluated directly  in your script,
since Vim  script is just  a chain  of ex commands  (those which begin  with a
colon). A function is not an ex command.

Let's come to the practical side, take a  look in what the user manual says in
chapter 41:

> #### 41.3  Expressions
>
> Vim has  a rich,  yet simple  way to  handle expressions.  You can  read the
>   definition  here: |expression-syntax|.  Here we  will show  the most  common
>   items.
>
> The numbers,  strings and  variables mentioned  above are  expressions by
>   themselves. Thus everywhere an expression is expected, you can use a number,
>   string or variable. Other basic items in an expression are:
>
> ```
>    $NAME        environment variable
>    &name        option
>    @r           register
> ```

The  expressions referred  here  aren't  the ex  commands.  Most  of the  time
expressions are evaluated in the commands arguments. This is a Vim expression:

```
i+=1
```

But you cant use it in Vim script  directly, since it's not an ex command. You
need something like:

```
:let i+=1
```

Now check the help for `:let`:

```
:let {var-name} = {expr1}                               :let E18
                        Set internal variable {var-name} to the result of the
                        expression {expr1}.  The variable will get the type
                        from the {expr}.  If {var-name} didn't exist yet, it
                        is created.
```

We're  looking  for `{expr1}`. This means  an  expression is expected — that's
what you need to check before using an ex command.

Back to the functions, note that the `:call` command then allows you to *call*
a function in an ex context.

So if  the command  being used  expects an expression  argument, go  ahead and
include  your functions,  and other  regular  stuff. They  will be  evaluated,
variables will  have their  value "yielded"  and so  on. The  `:execute` comes
handy if the command accepts a text argument. For example, if you need to move
the current line to  a line number stored in a variable, you  can use the `:m`
command. The help:

```
:[range]m[ove] {address}                        :m :mo :move E134
                        Move the lines given by [range] to below the line
                        given by {address}.
```

As you  can see, an  address is expected directly,  not an expression.  If you
have the number in a variable called `line` and do this:

```
:m line
```

That's  an error,  because there  is no  line numbered  `line`. Then  you need
`:exec` to evaluate  the expression before  executing it — that's what it does,
takes an expression as argument, evaluated it and executed as an ex command.

```
:exec "m " . line
"     ^^^^^^^^^^^
"     This expression evaluates to, say, "m 14" which is then executed
```